# Need random value from last x elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to get a random number from a list within a specific range, without using any module.

Input list looks like
`li = [12,44,55,64,34,54,56,43,56,9,87,89]`

I need a function where I should pass this list and `x` as inputs and get a random element from last `x` elements in the given list.

For example:
`val = getRandom(li, 4)`, the result `val` should be any one these values: `56,9,87,89`

**I tried with `random` module, it is working fine.**

```
def getRandomNumber(li, x):
    return random.choice(li[-x:])
```

Can anyone please help me to do achieve the same without the `random` module?

Comment: What did you try to solve that question (homework)?

Comment: not everything you need is what you get. Explain what you tried.

Comment: I already approached through ```random``` module. But I need to do it without using modules.

Comment: Randomness without any modules. Sounds like hell of a homework!

Comment: ... questions after answers have already been posted. See [this advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298799/12299000) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no answer yet that doesn't use `random` module... (Tested on CPython 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

This program uses no imports, gives a (potentially) satisfactory "random" result.  Remember that no random number generator is perfect, and this one certainly isn't the pick of the litter, but again, no imports

```py
s = 0
def randn(n):
    global s
    s += 1
    return hash(str(s)) % n

def get_random(sequence, n):
    i = randn(n) - n + len(sequence)
    return sequence[i]

li = [12,44,55,64,34,54,56,43,56,9,87,89]

print(get_random(li, 4))
```

Explanation:

`s = 0` this is the inital state (seed) of the random algorithm

`global s; s += 1` this increments the state every time `randn` is called so we don't get the same value every time

`hash(str(s))` the builtin `hash` creates an `int` [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the given object. The reason why we convert to string first, is because the hash of an `int` directly is (usually) itself.  The hashes of strings are consistent over the runtime of the program, but not over restarting the program (Tested in CPython), so even starting with `s = 0` always, we will get a different series of numbers upon restarting the program.

`% n` we are considering the hash result to be 1. pseudo-random, and 2. large.  Therefore if we take the modulus on `n`, and `n` is much smaller than the (large) value of the hash, the result should be a pseudo-random value from 0 to n-1.

`i = randn(n) - n + len(sequence)` get a random index of the last `n` indices of the sequence

Answer (score 6):

Use `random` module

```
import random

li = [12,44,55,64,34,54,56,43,56,9,87,89]

def getRandom(ls, x):
    return random.choice(ls[-x:])

print(getRandom(li, 4))
```

Comment: You forgot `ls[-x:]`

Answer (score 5):

To do this without copying a slice of the list, you can use `random.randint(-x, -1)` to generate an index in the range from `-x` to `-1` inclusive ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)). When you use a negative number as an index, it's calculated as an offset from the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try in this approach:

```
     import random

     li = [12,44,55,64,34,54,56,43,56,9,87,89]

     val = random.choice(li[-4:])
```

if you print your val, the answer should be one of last four number, for example:

```
     89
```